# Using own source code on slx.cloud?

Tags: parallel-processing, multicore

I created an account on slx.cloud and tested the available sample applications. Is there a place where I can upload my own source code though?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, thanks for trying it out! I am the product manager of [SLX.cloud](https://slx.cloud) (a free online version of our multicore optimization tools), so if you have any further questions you can ask me directly.

SLX.cloud currently offers two ways to import your own source code:

### 1. Importing via version control (recommended)

SLX.cloud allows you to import your code via git, github and SVN. You can start by creating a workspace using the `usermake` or `usercmake` template projects and after starting the workspace you can go to `Workspace -> Import Project` within the IDE.

It is also possible to import private repositories via Github. For that just go to `Preferences -> VCS` within the IDE and click the Github button in the bottom right corner to set up the SSH key for Github.

### 2. Importing via ZIP files

You can upload your source code as a ZIP file into the workspace, by going to `Workspace -> Import ZIP`

**NOTE:** The files will persist within the `/projects` folder if you stop the workspace, but not outside of it. Make sure to download your changes via `Workspace -> Export ZIP`. All files outside the `/projects` folder are updated on each start as we are loading the latest docker image for our tooling on startup.

**NOTE:** If you plan on sharing your workspace with coworkers and friends via the factory functionality, you will need to use version control to import the source code into the factory.

### 3. Tutorial from importing to analyzing your code

If you are interested in more details on analyzing your own code, I have created a [tutorial](https://docs.slx.cloud/docs/gettingstarted/your-own-code/index.html) on our documentation which includes importing your own code, but goes much further than that.